# I want to move selected elements/ focused elements only from left to right using angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to move elements from left to right only which are currently selected.
This is my current HTML code:

[image]

```
  <select class="panel-body treeSection {{lhsTreeSectionClass}}"
                                multiple="multiple">
   <option style="background-color: white;"  onmouseover="this.style.background='#A4D3FF';"
                                    onmouseout="this.style.background='#ffffff';"
                                    ng-repeat="avData in lhsTreeAV"
                                    ng-click="user_clicks_row(avData, $event)"> <!--Here on click of element I am calling controller method -->
{{avData}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </select>
```

Here I am calling controller method and adding value to an array list when any element is selected but instead of it I want to add the values to list to copy it to right pane only when I select any element and press the > button.

This is my controller code:

```
 $scope.user_clicks_row=function(avData, $event){
    $scope.avValue.push(avData);
    }
```

I want to pass only that elements to right side which are currently selected when I press > button for moving element from left to right.
Can someone please give me some pointers in solving this.

Comment: Have a property say 'isselected' in your array item and when you select an element make it to true (may be toggle the selection). Now when you press > item, check for all the isselected items and add them to the array used in the second block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by binding your `select` to a model in Controller, this way you have the selected options.

Here's an example:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c0e5fc9/5/)

### Edit

Fixed the Fiddle to iterate over the selected elements.

Comment: In your fiddle, if I select first element and press >> button, last element is also getting moved. I only want to send element to right which are only currently selected.

Comment: I've fixed the JSFiddle, please check it out